# Tools need to for low poly model, texture making & lighting in unity3d (iOS)

Tags: iphone, unity, lighting, low-poly

I am new to unity3d, i want to create a 3d game i have a team of 3d designers and programmers. My question which software should we use for modelling, texture making and advanced lighting for mobile to enhance game performance.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. "Which technology to use" questions are off-topic, unfortunately; please see the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately I would assume that your 3d modelers would suggest which software they prefer, as forcing them to use something different would be counter-productive. As for advanced lighting, Unity can take care of that. And for textures, I would say to check with the designers.

The free alternatives:

- Blender - 3D modelling and some basic texturing
- GIMP - Texturing/Bump Maps/Etc